# Xampp not running python

Tags: python, google-chrome, ubuntu, xampp

I am using **Xampp 7.2.6-0** on **ubuntu 16.04** with **Google Chrome   64.0.3282.186 (Official Build) (64-bit)**. I'm trying to run a python script through my browser. I have already edited the httpd.conf file in /opt/lampp/etc and appended the following lines.

```
#edit by Wade King

AddHandler cgi-script .py
ScriptInterpreterSource Registry-Strict
```

My python script is called docxReader.py and is in /opt/lampp/htdocs/PyFiles/XampPython/docxReader.py

It looks like this and compiles with no errors:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

print("Content-Type: text/html")
print("")
print("If you can read this inside a Web-Browser window, you can successfully run Python through XAMPP!'")
```

when I type http://localhost/PyFiles/XampPython/docxReader.py in my browser the result is the text of docxReader.py file like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

print("Content-Type: text/html")
print("")
print("If you can read this inside a Web-Browser window, you can successfully run Python through XAMPP!'")
```

I was expecting the page to display the output of my python file, not the text of the file itself. What is going on here, how do I configure Xampp to display the output of my python file?

Answer (score 0):

never mind I figured it out, I removed the

```
AddHandler cgi-script .py
ScriptInterpreterSource Registry-Strict
```

lines that I added to the end of the httpd.conf

then i found the line in httpd.conf:

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
```

and appended **.py** to the line

then i just ran `chmod +x docxReader.py` to make it executable and opened the file in my browser and it seems to work